# In Linux, why is there a global /dev/stdin file for all processes?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, stdin

Shouldn't the standard input for different process unique? If so, shouldn't the path of the stdin file be like `/dev/pid/stdin` instead of a global `/dev/stdin`?

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: But it *is* unique per process.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  Maybe request migration to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead (but check for duplicates there first).

Comment: There isn't. `/dev/stdin` is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd/0`.

Comment: @duskwuff on OSX,  it is a symbolic link to /dev/fd/0

Comment: @duskwuff what confused me more is how `/proc/self` can link to different file for different processes...

Comment: Think about how the string "/proc/self" is used.  Eventually, the process makes a system call and passes it that string.  The kernel uses that string to open a file.  It doesn't look at the filesystem and open a regular file.

Comment: because `/proc` is not a static file-system, it is dynamic. The “Files” are calculated, not retrieved.

Comment: On Debian `/dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0`, `/dev/fd -> /proc/self/fd/`, and to day in my terminal `/proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/8` (so `/dev` for file descripters is just a load of clever symlinks to `/proc` )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`/dev/stdin` is unique because

- it is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd/0`
- `/proc/self` is a symbolic link *only* seen by your running process to *its* process-id

The `/proc` filesystem is a ***virtual*** (not ***real***) filesystem which has the ability to show a different view to each process.

Further reading:

- [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy: 1.14. /proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)
- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3: Reference Guide: Chapter 5. The proc File System](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/ch-proc.html)